# Java line.split() for csv file returning empty strings

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I'm trying to read from this CSV file that looks like

```
"1.23","2.45","3.25"
"4","5","6"
"7","8","9"
"10","11","12"
```

Now the problem is that while Java can find my file, line split isn't returning what I'm expecting.

Here is my attempt at reading from the csv file.

```
          File root = new  File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").toURI());
          File resource = new File(root, "coords.csv");
          float[] x = new float[5000];
                     float[] y = new float[5000];
                     float[] z = new float[5000];
                     int coordIndex = 0; 
                     BufferedReader br = null; 
                     String line = "";
                     String cvsSplitBy = ",";
                     /* 1, 2, 3,
                      * 3, 5, 6,
                      */
                     try{
                         System.out.println(coordIndex);
                         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resource));
                         String[] coordinates = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
/*I get an error from accessing an array out of bounds */ 
                         System.out.println(coordinates[0]);
                         System.out.println(coordinates[1]);
                         System.out.println(coordinates[2]);
                         x[coordIndex] = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[0]);
                         y[coordIndex] = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[1]);
                         z[coordIndex] = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[2]);
                         coordIndex++;
                     }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     } finally {
                        if (br != null) {
                            try {
                                br.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                     }
```

Here is my output error:

```
IOException:  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Get rid of quotes (`"`) first with `replaceAll()` and then split by comma (`,`). As of know your are leaving both leading and trailing quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String line = "";
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resource));
String[] coordinates = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
```

You never have data in your `line`.

You have to add a loop to read everything:

```
while(line = br.readLine() != null) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `line` you are  splitting is the empty line. This results in `split` returning an empty array.

The error you get is typical for non-defensive programming: the result of split() depends entirely on user input (that you do not know ex ante), hence it is a **must** to check the result:

```
coords = line.split(",");
if (coords.length == 3) {
      // looks good
}
else {
  System.err.println("Bad data: " + line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`line` is empty. You're never assigning a value other than `""`...